# JavaScript RegEx How to match only numbers seperetad by non-numeric characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm a beginner in JavaScript. And I have some problem in RegEx.

```
var string="Find the mean, median, mode of the following data. Concatenate the three averages and the data values at positions 176 and 345."
var pos=string.match().
```

How do I save the "values at positions **176** and **345**" numbers in this text to the *pos* using regex?

Comment: What about `abc123def`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var string="Find the mean, median, mode of the following data. Concatenate the three averages and the data values at positions 176 and 345."
var pos=string.match(/\b\d+\b/g);
console.log(pos);
```

This would store all your numbers in an array **pos**